# Operator delete[] (overloaded) and destructor connection

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, delete-operator

So I've got a class in which i use overloaded operators new[] and delete[] to track how much memory is allocated and freed back.

```
class TvectorPublic
{
public:
    int x, y, z;
    
    TvectorPublic(int x_1 = 0,int y_1 = 0,int z_1 = 0) : x(x_1),y(y_1),z(z_1)
    {}

    void m_DoubleValue()
    {
        x *= 2;
        y *= 2;
        z *= 2;
    }

    void m_AddingValue(int value)
    {
        x += value;
        y += value;
        z += value;
    }

    void* operator new[](size_t size_1)
    {
        std::cout << "Creating TvectorPublic object.\n";
        std::cout << "Reserving memory: " << size_1 << " bytes.\n";

        return (::new char[size_1]);
    }

    void operator delete[](void* pointer, size_t size_1) noexcept
    {
        if (pointer)
        {
                std::cout << "\nDeleting TvectorPublic object.\n";
            std::cout << "Freeing memory: " << size_1 << " bytes.\n";

            ::delete[] static_cast<char*>(pointer);
        }
    }
};
```

In function main() I define an array of objects of this class:

```
TvectorPublic* pointer_1 = new TvectorPublic[3];
    std::cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        std::cout << pointer_1[i] << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    delete[] pointer_1;
```

The output is that memory reserved is 36 bytes but memory freed is only 12 bytes.
The problem seems to disappear after defining destructor:

```
~TvectorPublic()
    {
        std::cout << "DestructorCalled\n";
    }
```

Then the output is: Memory reserved: 40 bytes, memory freed: 40 bytes.
My question is about correlation between destructor and this operator delete.

1.) Why without destructor there is a memory leak and why complier is not generating default one in this case?

2.) Why is Memory reserved 4 bytes bigger with this destructor (which actually does nothing except visually representing process of destroying objects in this array)?

3.) Why only after adding this destructor whole memory reserved is freed? (This is bothering me because I dont see any connection between destructor and operator delete except that delete is calling destructor which does nothing. Problem does not exist when in the main function I am not creating an array of object but single object. Then it frees all of the memory reserved by operator new even without constructor).

Edit:
I forgot to include overloaded operator << for outputing vector's array:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& screen, TvectorPublic &vector_obj)
{
    screen << "(" << vector_obj.x << ", " << vector_obj.y << ", " << vector_obj.z << ")";
    return screen;
}
```

Comment: The reason for the extra bytes when there's a destructor is that the compiler has to call the destructor on each element of the array. To do that it has to know how many elements are in the array; the extra space is for storing the element count.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ok, that makes sense to me. Any ideas about other two concerns?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Might make a difference.

Comment: @MarkRansom msvc 14.29.30133, other compliers like gcc or clang and they're just working fine so i guess its msvc bug.

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time I thought I'd found a compiler bug and it turned out to be my own misunderstanding, I'd be rich.  But in your case I just don't have a clue.

Comment: There are weird rules about `operator delete` and when it should or should not have the second `size_t` param and which one is called in what situation, which depend on whether or not the class has a virtual destructor.  See 5.3.5 para 10 (of the C++17 spec -- other versions have different numbering).  You may be running into something related to this.